# How to pair with or connect to an OneOdio Pro C wireless Headphone on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, headphones

The [OneOdio Pro C wireless Headphone](https://www.oneodio.com/collections/wired-wireless-headphones/products/pro-c-wired-wireless-headphones) supports these Bluetooth protocols: HFP/HSP/A2DP/AVRCP

```
$ dpkg --status bluez | grep '^Version:'
Version: 5.53-0ubuntu3.4

$ pactl list short | grep -i bluetooth
7   module-bluetooth-policy 
8   module-bluetooth-discover

$ dmesg | grep Bluetooth
[    5.067745] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.067761] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.067764] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.067765] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.067768] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.087810] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 121 week 36 2020
[   12.806192] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   12.806197] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   12.806201] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   27.876087] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   27.876099] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   27.876106] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11

$ systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-12-16 13:43:27 +00; 1 day 19h ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1755 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 115424)
     Memory: 8.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1755 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Dec 18 00:56:52 machine bluetoothd[1755]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Dec 18 00:56:57 machine bluetoothd[1755]: 85:62:35:17:5B:A1: error updating services: Host is down (112)
Dec 18 00:56:57 machine bluetoothd[1755]: connect error: Host is down (112)
Dec 18 01:07:54 machine bluetoothd[1755]: Unable to get Headset Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down
Dec 18 01:08:01 machine bluetoothd[1755]: Unable to get Headset Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down
Dec 18 01:08:08 machine bluetoothd[1755]: Unable to get Headset Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down
Dec 18 01:08:27 machine bluetoothd[1755]: Unable to get Headset Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down
Dec 18 02:20:53 machine bluetoothd[1755]: connect error: Connection timed out (110)
Dec 18 02:20:53 machine bluetoothd[1755]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Dec 18 02:20:59 machine bluetoothd[1755]: 85:62:35:17:5B:A1: error updating services: Host is down (112)
```

What can I do to get these two devices to pair and connect?

I tried:

```
$ bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# pair 85:62:35:17:5B:A1
Attempting to pair with 85:62:35:17:5B:A1
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists
[bluetooth]# trust 85:62:35:17:5B:A1
Changing 85:62:35:17:5B:A1 trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# connect 85:62:35:17:5B:A1
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

I did try `$ pulseaudio -k` as advised by [this wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bluetooth_headset) and retried the connect command but still can't connect.

I noticed that this wiki said that `pulseaudio-alsa` package is needed. I tried and discovered that this package cannot be located. Is my problem caused by no `pulseaudio-alsa` pkg?

```
$ sudo apt install pulseaudio-alsa
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pulseaudio-alsa

$ dpkg -l | grep pulseaudio
ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64              1.16.2-1ubuntu2.1                                 amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  pulseaudio                                 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13                             amd64        PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth                1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13                             amd64        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-utils                           1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13                             amd64        Command line tools for the PulseAudio sound server
```

Comment: I assume your device works with other systems?  Switch on the device. Click settings. Click bluetooth. Ensure top slider shows a colour (on).  Allow the system time to find for the device. Click the device. This should connect your headset, assuming your headset is compatible with the protocol you have. If the device disconnects, repeat process. Then click device, then click the slider bar. You may need to repeat this a few times until your device connects properly.

Comment: @robgrune I have done what you had described before. Repeat several times, still failed. Also tried pairing with other Ubuntu 20.04 systems with diff. hardwares. Still can't pair/connect. Headphone did pair/connect with mobile phone to play music before.

Comment: You are sure the BT on your machine works?  Is your BT onboard, or a usb dongle? Ensure both the machine and device have same generation of BT, eg BT2.  A BT2 will not connect to BT1.  If you cannot connect the device to any linux machine, the device is suspect.  I have various BT devices; phone, pad, mouse, kb, headsets, etc - all work.

Comment: @robgrune System's BT works with other BT devices. Headphone's BT is able to pair with other devices but not with Ubuntu 20.04 systems.

Comment: You have 2 potential issues: 1 connect the BT; 2 device compatibility.   issue 1... Is your machine bluetooth onboard or a dongle? I suspect you need to upgrade the Linux side to bluetooth5. Suggest you get a new usb5 dongle.   issue 2... if after connect, the device has no sound, likely incompatible with pulseaudio. In which case, you will need an alternative, like pipewire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best solution is to just upgrade Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. The newer Ubuntu 22.04 version connects to OneOdio Pro C wireless Headphones effortlessly and works perfectly.